# discord rewrite How to make bot delete data when left a server

Tags: json, discord.py

How can i make my bot remove its data from json file when it leaves a server.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_leave(guild):
    guildname = str(guild)
    with open("serverchannel.json") as jsong_file:
        data = json.load(jsong_file)
    data = data.remove(guildname)
    with open("serverchannel.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

`on_guild_leave()` is not a client event, you should be using [`on_guild_remove()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=event#discord.on_guild_remove), which is called whenever the client is no longer in a guild anymore. Reasons can include leaving, getting banned, getting kicked, and the guild being deleted.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    guildname = guild.name
    with open("serverchannel.json") as jsong_file:
        data = json.load(jsong_file)
    data = data.remove(guildname)
    with open("serverchannel.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```